# C++ - Check if all template arguments are power of 2

Tags: templates, c++11, constexpr, variadic

I`am trying to find a simple way of checking if parameters passed as template arguments are all power of 2. I found a bithack on the website and I have this:

```
constexpr bool isPowerOf2(size_t value){
return !(value == 0) && !(value & (value - 1));
}
```

This works nice for single value but applying this to multiple arguments looks ugly.

```
static_assert(isPowerOf2(Arg1), "Argument must be a power of 2");
static_assert(isPowerOf2(Arg2), "Argument must be a power of 2");
static_assert(isPowerOf2(Arg3), "Argument must be a power of 2");
```

It would be better if I could make it look like arePowersOf2(Arg1, Arg2, Arg3), but im not really advanced in template magic. So my question: Is there an easy way of doing it? I would prefer constexpr C++11 solution.

Comment: Your function is not a template, and the parameters are not template arguments.

Comment: can you use C++1z, like [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aaf39b0e4bf7ff77) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can write a `conjunction` trait which checks if all the `bool`s in a parameter pack are `true`. This example uses [@Columbo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3647361/columbo)'s `bool_pack` trick:

```
template <bool...> struct bool_pack{};
template <bool... bools> 
struct conjunction : std::is_same<bool_pack<true, bools...>,
                                  bool_pack<bools..., true>>
{};

template <size_t... Args>
constexpr bool arePowerOf2() {
    return conjunction<isPowerOf2(Args)...>::value;   
}
```

Then you would just call it like this:

```
arePowerOf2<Args...>();
arePowerOf2<Arg1, Arg2, Arg3>();
```

[<kbd>Live Demo</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/345bfe91d0841cb4)

---

In C++1z you can use [fold expressions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) for this:

```
template <size_t... Args>
constexpr bool arePowerOf2() {
    return (... && isPowerOf2(Args));
}
```

---

C++1z will also get [`std::conjunction`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction), which is just slightly different from the version above.

Comment: That's pretty cute!

Comment: C++1z offers very simple solution but unfortunately I`am limited to only use C++0x. But Your trick with conjuction works nicely for me. Thank you.

Comment: `bool_pack` off-by-one is such a hack.  :p

Comment: @Yakk Such a horribly gorgeous hack.

Answer (score 1):

A pack of bools is an integer sequence of bools:

```
template<bool...Bs>using bools = std::integer_sequence<bool, Bs...>;
```

These help you create a sequence of `true, true, true` of a specified length:

```
template<std::size_t...Is>
constexpr bools<(Is,true)...> make_trues_f( std::index_sequence<Is...> ) {
  return {};
}
template<std::size_t N>
using make_trues_t = decltype( all_true_f( std::make_index_sequence<N>{} ) );
template<class...Ts>
using make_trues_for_t = make_trues_t<sizeof...(Ts)>;
```

which gives you:

```
static_assert(
  std::is_same<
    bools<isPowerOf2(Args)...>,
    make_trues_for_t<Args...>
  >::value, "Argument must be a power of 2"
);
```

or

```
template<class...Args>
constexpr std::is_same<
    bools<isPowerOf2(Args)...>,
    make_trues<sizeof...(Args)>
  >
all_power_of_2() { return {}; }
```

Me, I like returning types even from `constexpr` functions when I know the answer at a type-computation level.

As a bonus, the failed comparison is more clearly what is intended, instead of an off-by-one hack.  The `is_same` compares a sequence of `<true, true, false, true>` to `<true, true, true, true>`, as compared to the off-by-one hack which compares `<true, true, true, false, true>` to `<true, true, false, true, true>`.  In the first case, it is really clear from the type what went wrong -- the `false` -- especially when you spot that the right hand side is always a pack of only `true`.